# callback url in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on the Flutter app, and need to create a callback URL after
a customer success/fails payment. Which event/function can be used with [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)?

I checked the same questions here but didn't find solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create webview client and use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` or `onLoadResource` to create a callback url in **webview_flutter**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and do what you want in **navigationDelegate** callback

```
WebView(
                initialUrl: yourPaymenntUrl,
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                navigationDelegate: (navigationDelegate) async {

                  if (navigationDelegate.url
                      .contains(yourReturnUrl)) {
                    // payment completed
                    // do what ever you want
                   String? merchantId = Uri.parse(navigationDelegate.url)
                   .queryParameters['merchantId'];
                    Navigator.pop(context, merchantId);
                  } else if (navigationDelegate.url
                      .contains(cancelUrl)) {
                    // TODO implementation
                   Navigator.pop(context);
                  }

                  return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                },
              )
```